# 画面の回転に合わせてセル内のViewの幅を変えたい

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

画面が横向きになるとそれに応じて`TableView`のセル内の`View`の幅を変えたいのですが、以下の画像のように横向きになってもセル内の`View`の幅が変わりません。ちなみに緑の部分は`ScrollView`となっています。

縦向き
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

横向き
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`viewWillTransitionToSize`内で`scrollView.contentSize`としてもサイズは変わりませんでした。どうすれば画面の回転によってセル内の`View`のサイズを変えることができるでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: AutoLayoutを使って解決したいと考えますか？iPhoneだけでも、画面サイズが4種類になった現在、AutoLayoutを使わないのは非現実的だと思います。AutoLayoutを使いたくないとお考えだとしても、一考されることをお勧めします。

Comment: @Harawo ご回答ありがとうございます。はい、今後のことを考えると、できればAutoLayoutを使って解決したいです。AutoLayoutを使ってScrollViewを横画面サイズぴったりに調節することができました。しかし、画像が伸びてしまったり、スクロール量がおかしかったりするので、色々やってみてわからないことがあればまた質問させていただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto Layoutを使って、ビューのサイズをコントロールする方法を説明します。

まず、UITableViewCellのサイズは、UITableViewの横幅と、行の高さ（Row Height）に追従します。画面のたてよこの向きを変えたり、プログラムで行の高さを変更すると、UITableViewCellのサイズも変わります。このサイズの変化に、セルに貼り付けたUIScrollViewのサイズを追従させたいなら、下図のような、Constraintsの設定を行います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

（テキストフィールド内の数値は、無視してください。）
上下左右のConstraintsを指定することで、スクロールビューのサイズは可変となります。

つぎに、スクロールビューの内部、コンテンツ内のConstraintsの設定に移ります。
Constraintsを設定しないと、**コンテンツのサイズ**（UIScrollViewのプロパティcontentSize）**は不定です**。不足のないConstraintsの設定で、はじめてコンテンツのサイズが決まります。これは重要なポイントです。
左右に長いスクロールビューの場合、左端のサブビューのConstraintsと、右端のサブビューのConstraintsによって、最小限のコンテンツサイズを決定する条件がそろいます。
左端のサブビューのConstraints

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

5箇所指定していることに注目してください。
つぎに右端のサブビューのConstraints

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

こちらは4箇所。上下のサイズ決定は、左端のサブビューで行っているので、右端のサブビューでは不用というわけです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。詳しく解説してくださり、とても参考になります。まだAutoLayoutには慣れてないのですが、上記の回答を参考にしながらひとまずレイアウトを組んでみたいと思います。